# Getting current user name in DotNetNuke using javascript

Tags: javascript, dotnetnuke

I would like to get the current user name in DotNetNuke using javascript and use it in some js fuction like:

```
alert(DotNetNuke.User.Name)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to add a `Text/HTML` module to a page.

In the module settings of that module, check the `Replace Tokens` option on the `HTML Module Settings` tab.

Now you can use the tokens and add text to that module (use Basic Text Box when using JavaScript).

```
<script> alert('Hello my name is [User:DisplayName]'); </script>
```

Full list of tokens [here](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/tokens).

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be

```
alert('<%= UserController.Instance.GetCurrentUserInfo().DisplayName %>')
```

but you have to import:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="DotNetNuke.Entities.Users" %>
```